# A weird conflict between bootstrap library and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please dont think that i am asking this question without any research. I have done it already.
My Question is, i am using bootstrap library for toggle menu slide (accordion toggle) which actually toggle the dropdown of `<li>`.
In addition to this i am also using my custom jquery `<script>`

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#user-button').on('click',function(f){
            $('.dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
        });

        /*mobile menu*/
        var m_menu = $('#menu').clone();
        m_menu.addClass('m-menu');
        m_menu.prependTo('body');

        var m_menu_btn = $('<div id="m-menu-btn"><img src="images/mbtn.png"/></div>');
        m_menu_btn.prependTo('body');

        $('#m-menu-btn').on('click',function(){
            $(m_menu).slideToggle();
            $('#m-menu-btn img').animate({width: (this.tog ^= 1) ? 45 : 70 },400);
        });

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

The above code prepends the `div` to body which in fact is a mobile menu. secondly it does toggle slide on click as you can see in the code.

Now the problem is after putting this code just after bootstrap library, the bootstrap library code which is toggle accordion doesn't seemed to work.

Help me pls..

Comment: If put before those mentioned libarary, it work?

Comment: no it doesn't. actually they both work separately.

Comment: Why the people degrade this question when i i said that i have done this research.. If they know the answer , why dont they answer. asholes

Comment: When you click this `$('#user-button').on('click',function(f){` it work? or this code `$('#m-menu-btn').on('click',function(){` ?

Comment: yes this works. but botstrap (acordion toggle ) doesnt.. The bootstrap (accordion toggle) only work if i remove my jquery script (mobile menu) from document.

Comment: try change `$('#m-menu-btn').on('click',function(){` into `$(document).on('click','#m-menu-btn',function(){`

Comment: did so, no effect. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one for down voting...

Real thanks to @Norlihazmey Ghazali for participating.

I managed to solve the above Question.
What i did is, i removed that bootstrap library link.
Then i added some lines of code in my script.
Actually the accordion menu each `<li>` has a class of .`panel`. So i wrote.

```
$('.panel').on('click',function()
    {
        if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible'))
        {
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.panel').children('ul').slideUp();
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        }
    });
```